# Extract rows using select query

Tags: mysql

I have two queries shown below.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `nhrd_members` B
 WHERE Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
 AND `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
 AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2015-01-01'
```

which yields 98 rows..

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `nhrd_members` A
 WHERE Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
 AND `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
 AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2014-05-14'
```

which yields 19 rows.

As you can see i am extracting the data from the same table. Now the actual result what i need is 98-19 i.e 79  rows.

I need to exclude the rows of query 2 from  query 1. and get 81 records.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are both tables having same columns ?

Comment: Both are same tables and also having same columns

Comment: @ShreyasTg:- Do you have ID column in  your table?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM `nhrd_members` B
WHERE
  Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
  AND (
    `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
    AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2015-01-01'
  )
  AND NOT (
    `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
    AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2014-05-14'
  )
```

that can be simplified as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `nhrd_members` B
WHERE
  Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
  AND (
    `Member_FromDate` > '2014-05-14'
    AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2015-01-01'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query-

```
SELECT *
 FROM `nhrd_members` B
 WHERE Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
 AND `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
 AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2015-01-01' where id not in (SELECT id
 FROM `nhrd_members` A
 WHERE Membership_Number LIKE 'A%'
 AND `Member_FromDate` >= '2014-01-01'
 AND `Member_FromDate` <= '2014-05-14');
```